# Why does pinging makes UDP work faster for GSM module Telit GL865?

Tags: udp, ping, stm32, gsm, tftp

I have implemented my own TFTP library for STM32 on Keil using GSM Telit GL865 via Uart.

I realized that, if I command continuous pinging starting from the initialization, TFTP packages are exhanged fast.

If I do not start continuously pinging the system at the initialization, packets are exchanged slower.

Do you have any idea why pinging makes GSM module's UDP server socket work faster? This is a little bit weird actually.

Comment: Maybe it is preventing module from getting into sleep/low energy mode

Comment: The modem is set to "mobile full functionality with power saving disabled (factory default)".

Answer (score 1):

TCP/UDP data is probably not received continuosly but every *timeout_recv* milliseconds (I suppose in order to limit power consumption, even if full power saving is disabled).

Sending PING requests you are probably triggering asynchronous wake-ups, that force recvs to be done more often and speeding up the entire communication.